# Custom font in JLabel is cut off

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jlabel, flowlayout

I have a JLabel that I have set the custom font, "BP Diet" to it. If I add this to a JFrame, the text appears fine, but as soon as I change the layout of the JFrame to FlowLayout, the top of the text appears cut off. This same problem occurs when you add the JLabel to a JPanel and add that to the JFrame. I have the font available at http://www.hichris.com/more/files/BPdiet.otf

Here is the code below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class FontSizeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(
                "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKk");
        label.setFont(createFont());
        frame.add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getMinimumSize());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static Font createFont() {
        Font customFont = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.hichris.com/more/files/BPdiet.otf");
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            customFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(customFont);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return customFont.deriveFont(25f);
    }
}
```

### As it should appear

[image: Showing full font]

### As it appears after `pack()`

[image: As it first appears]

### Bigger view pointing out the dots above i & j

[image: As it first appears]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm running your code and nothing gets cut off

Comment: When you un-comment the setLayout method it get's cut off :)

Comment: ok so it isn't cutting, it's just moving it up from the middle. Is it ok? I mean my logic?

Comment: No, the thing is actually cut off, if you zoom in you can see that the top of the "i" is cut off but it is just at the top of the screen. If you make multiple Labels you can see that they all get cut off at the top. That is what's weird. I'm thinking that the font is bigger than a regular font and that is why it is cut off. I can also set the minimum size of the label and it is still cut off.

Comment: Does anybody know why this could be?

Comment: @peeskillet  I see the problem on Windows 7.  Try the edited source.  It vaguely reminds me of a problem where the font did not return correct size information..

Comment: BTW - one hack/work-around is `label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 0, 0, 0));`..

Comment: @AndrewThompson the font does return the correct size, _kinda_. It's the `i` that's the black sheep of the font family. It doesn't want to adhere to the accent restrictions :-)

Comment: A solution could be to create a class with an array of fonts and their corresponding border.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an observation. (code at bottom)

[image]

I got the font metrics of the font and drew a line where the accent and base line of the font are. You can clearly see that the dot in the `i` goes above the above the accent line, which is the cutoff. The preferred size of the label is calculated using the metrics. So based of the this, the preferred size will cut off part of the `i`. The bottom of the `j` will not get cut off though, as the descender line is taken into account.

As for why the message gets cut off, there could be a few reason. In your original code, the problem wasn't encountered, possibly because the font was too small, and the FlowLayout has a default 5px gap. In the new example it cut off, using `pack()` because the default BorderLayout *has* no default gap.

You can fix this, like AndrewThompson mentioned, by just using an `EmptyBorder`, or specify the gap for the layout. Things to consider are that `FlowLayout` respects preferred size of components, so the label will get set to its preferred size, taking the font metrics into consideration. The `BorderLayout` will *not* respect preferred sizes, and for the label, will stretch the label to fit the layout position and center the text vertically

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class FontSizeTest {
    static String message = "AaBbHhIiJjKk";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createFontTestPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getMinimumSize());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static Font font = createFont();

    static JPanel createFontTestPanel() {
        return new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setFont(font);
                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                int stringHeight = fm.getAscent();
                int stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(message);

                int beginString = getWidth()/2 - stringWidth/2;
                int baseString = getHeight()/2 + stringHeight/2;

                // draw accent line
                g.drawLine(0, baseString - stringHeight, getWidth(), baseString - stringHeight);
                // draw base line
                g.drawLine(0, baseString, getWidth(), baseString);
                // draw message
                g.drawString(message, beginString, baseString);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, 150);
            }
        };
    }

    static Font createFont() {
        Font customFont = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.hichris.com/more/files/BPdiet.otf");
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            customFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(customFont);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return customFont.deriveFont(50f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the desired empty border size based on the size of the font?

Comment: The thing is the FontMetrics _is_ supposed to figure out the size of the font. Something is screwy with your font, causing it not to take into account the points of the `i` and `j`. So I don't think there is a way, for this font in particular

Answer (score 1):

I installed the font and used `setFont` method from [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setFont%28java.awt.Font%29) this way:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//Un-commenting causes text to be cut off
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(
                "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz");
        label.setFont(new Font("BPDiet", Font.BOLD, 15));
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I deleted your method and setted font in an easier way, if you still need that method, then just reply so I can try adding or solving the issue.

Try it and tell me if it helps :)

Comment: How would I specify where the font is? I would still have to register the font with the createFont() method? Just not returning anything?

Comment: Font looks on the default fonts folder on your system, so you don't have to do anything but installing it. Have you tried the program? Not returning anything from where?

Comment: The font is not a default one on the system. I must specify it from I file I assume? I do not want to have the user install it either.

Comment: hmmph then let me try to fix it to your needs :)

Comment: Also, I installed the font onto my system and the top of the font is still cut off. I used the code you gave me and It does not work as wanted. http://screencast.com/t/BOyVqMyEQ0Y

Comment: @user3669858 can you post an image of the actual output? If not enough rep. post link and I edit it

Comment: @user3669858 can't see it, provide the link where it is uploaded

Comment: screencast.com/t/BOyVqMyEQ0Y